# absolute position inside relative position goes outside the borders

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I want to make the logo at the bottom of the picture so it will look like a watermarked picture with a logo.

Now the problem is that the absolute position is going outside the border and goes to the bottom of the page.

I'm quite sure that a small tweak can change the picture here (double meaning).

The jsFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/PMc62/

Here is my Code :

Html :

```
<section>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <img src="http://www.reactive.com/Media/images/hero-ripcurl-01-2615749e-fba2-47da-abc7-d0ea3a9ecfbd-0-600x450.jpg" width=600 height=450>
            <img src="https://puaction.com/img/logo.png" width=300 height=65>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120217141950/lego/images/6/67/Lego_lotr_2012_gollum-600x450.jpg" width=600 height=450>
                <img src="https://puaction.com/img/logo.png" width=300 height=65>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
            </section>
```

The css:

```
section ul:first-child li {
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 600px;
}

section ul:first-child li a img:nth-child(2) {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 65px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
section ul:first-child li {
    height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
}
```

position relative is missing on li

Hope this will resolve your issue - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PMc62/3/)

Comment: I thought position: relative; is DEFAULT :) Thanks man ! Super ! Need to wait 6 min to accept your answer. Thank you sooo much !

Comment: No Probs Happy Coding!

Comment: @user3447293, `position:static` is default. That's why you'll (almost) never see it explicitly styled.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `li` item `position:relative`. W hen you use absolute position on an element, use relative position to its parent element. Otherwise absolute position values like `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` will be calculated with respect to the `body`.

```
section ul:first-child li {
    position: relative;
}
```